# How to change this program to be well for the parallel processing

Tags: fortran, fortran90, fortran95

I am learning about parallel processing.
The below program, I want to change it to be well for the parallel processing, but I don't know whether I am correct or not.

Original code:

```
programe test
   implicit none
   integer i
   real x, a(1000)
   do i = 1, 1000, 1
      a(i) = real(i - 1)
      x = sin( a(i) * 3.1415926 / 180.0e0 )
      write( *, *) a(i), x
  enddo
end program test
```

Below is my version:

```
programe test
   implicit none
   integer i
   real a(1000), x(1000)
   do i = 1, 1000, 1
      a(i) = real(i-1)
   enddo
   do i = 1, 1000, 1
      x(i) = sin( a(i) * 3.1415926 / 180.0e0)
   enddo
   write (*,*) (a(i), x(i), i = 1, 1000, 1)
end programe test
```

Am I correct?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes the second version is better for parallelisation, in particular it removes the potential data race on the scalar `x` and the issues that will arise from `write`-ing inside a parallelised loop.  But why bother with two loops ? You could fuse them together without changing the meaning of the program.  And don't expect significant speedup for such a small program.

Comment: Pre computing the degreee-radians first, and then using that in the loop, is also a time saver.